# Yii2 Сохранение страницы пагинации

Tags: yii2, gridview, pagination

Такая проблема есть обычный вывод товаров в админке через GridView с пагинацией, проблема в том, что после изменения товара происходит редирект на первую страницу пагинации, а мне хотелось бы сохранять данное положение т.е. если отредактировал товар на 5 странице то и возвратило тебя на 5 страницу, но хз как такое сделать. Ну и если кому интересно как у меня идет сохранение то вот код:

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load($post)) {
        $success = $model->validate();
        $success &= $model->loadFeatures($post);
        $success &= $model->validateFeatures();

        $success2 = $model->validate();
        $success2 &= $model->loadOptions($post);
        $success2 &= $model->validateOptions();

        if ($success && $success2) {
            $model->description = preg_replace("!<a.*?href=\"?'?([^ \"'>]+)\"?'?.*?>(.*?)</a>!is", "\\2", $model->description);
            if ($model->nds == '' || $model->nds == null) {
                $model->nds = null;
            }
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['index', 'brand' => $model->brand_id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

И да не спрашивайте почему сохранение именно таким образом.

Comment: Очень скверный подход. В actionCreate такая же портянка кода небось. Обработку description почему бы не вынести в beforeSave(), а что там с nds происходит, не совсем понятно для чего.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, тут скорее даже не в beforeSave вынести, а в отдельный behavior правильнее будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вернуться на предыдущую страницу, необходимо сохранить ее адрес. Сохранить можно куда угодно, один из вариантов это сессии. Перед тем, как записать реферрер, обязательно проверяем, не был ли он записан ранее. Например апдэйт записи не получился и у нас уже неактуальный реферрер. Поэтому перед установкой првоеряем, после успешного редактирования удаляем. Приблизительно так.

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $sessionName = 'referrer';
    $session = Yii::$app->session;

    // проверяем на случай, если редактирование записи не прокатило
    if(!$session->hasFlash($sessionName)){
        $session->setFlash($sessionName, Yii::$app->request->referrer);
    }

    if ($model->load($post) && $model->save()) {
        // все валидации и реплэйсы уж точно не в этом месте
        // надо вынести в модель или в бехевиор, как посоветовал LANSELOT

        // получаем реферрер и удаляем
        $url = $session->getFlash($sessionName);
        return $this->redirect($url);
    }

    return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
}
```